# Case-sensitive Tinysort with Bootstrap sortable table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tinysort

The [Tinysort documentation](https://github.com/Sjeiti/TinySort) says that case-sensitive sorting can be configured with:

```
tinysort.default.cases = true;
```

I've added that configuration JavaScript to my web page before a table with the Bootstrap `sortable` class, but the Tinysort configuration doesn't seem to have any effect.

How do I configure Tinysort for a case-sensitive sort?

Comment: You are in accordance with the [docs](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#option-cases). That leaves either your config statement not getting active or a bug in Tinysort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to change a line of code in `bootstrap-sortable.js` to add the `cases: true` (yes, I had omitted the `s` previously, but changing that had no effect):

```
rows.tsort('td:eq(' + sortColumn + ')', { order: sortOrder, attr: 'data-value', cases: true });
```

Now all of my tables are hard-coded with `cases: true`, but previously they had been (implicitly) hard-coded with `cases: false`.

It would be nice to have a way to inject this option without altering the third-party code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot an  -s-.
It should be:

```
tinysort.defaults.cases = true;
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Sjeiti/hLe7cvxs/

Comment: This still doesn't seem to work for me with a bootstrap sortable table. Maybe the fiddle can be updated...

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: you set the `tinysort.defaults.cases = true;` -and- you have a `table.sortable`, and that's it? No other code? That will indeed do nothing. Did you have a look at [the sorting table example](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#sorting-tables)?